# Merging Series to Single Output - pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want a single series as the output and not multiple series like below:

Current Output:

```
0    5.98% to 35.89%
1           1% to 6%
dtype: object
0    1% to 6%
dtype: object
0    6.99% to 24.99%
1    6.99% to 24.99%
2    6.99% to 24.99%
3    6.99% to 24.99%
dtype: object
0    6.99% to 24.99%
dtype: object
```

Desired Output:

```
0    5.98% to 35.89%
1           1% to 6%
0    1% to 6%
0    6.99% to 24.99%
1    6.99% to 24.99%
2    6.99% to 24.99%
3    6.99% to 24.99%
0    6.99% to 24.99%
dtype: object
```

However with my current code I can't get the series to consolidate. I have attempted to make it into a dataframe with all the information I want appended to it; however, when trying to combine all the dataframes in the output I haven't been able to get it to combine either. I know I am running a loop before the creation of the dataframe for the regex operator I am doing to some text before creating the strings/dataframe which is most likely causing the multiple outputs. **Is there a way I can combine it post loop?** Code below:

```
paragraph = soup.find_all(text=re.compile('[0-9]%'))
for n in paragraph:
    matches = []
    matches.extend(re.findall('(?i)\d+(?:\.\d+)?%\s*(?:to|-)\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?%', n.string))
    sint = pd.Series(matches)
    if sint.empty:
        continue
    print(sint)
```

With Edits:

```
    paragraph = soup.find_all(text=re.compile('[0-9]%'))
    vals = []
    for n in paragraph:
        matches = re.findall('(?i)\d+(?:\.\d+)?%\s*(?:to|-)\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?%', n.string)
        vals.append(pd.Series(matches))
sint = pd.concat(vals)
print(sint)
```

New Output:

```
0    6.99% to 24.99%
dtype: object
```

Comment: This "output" you posted is the result from `print(sint)`?

Comment: Yes. My intention was to combine sint first and then push everything into a dataframe. I will clean up the code to show my intent. Sorry. @RafaelC

Answer (score 1):

Store your values and use `pd.concat` afterwards

```
paragraph = soup.find_all(text=re.compile('[0-9]%'))
vals = []
for n in paragraph:
    matches = re.findall('(?i)\d+(?:\.\d+)?%\s*(?:to|-)\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?%', n.string)
    vals.append(pd.Series(matches))
```

Then just

```
>>> pd.concat(vals)
```

Comment: This ended up creating more series with more duplicates. I am updating the post from the suggested improvements and the new outputs. Is there a method that can just stack the series on top of each other as the loop is iterating through the 'paragraph' variable

Comment: @dtrinh, I think your `concat` should go outside the for loop.

Comment: @jpp when I do that it takes the last row generated in the for loop

Comment: Updated code with the concat moved outside of the loop